# Separate dynamic and static parts of REST service

Tags: php, rest, caching

Imagine that we have large list of products that is taken from database, converted to array and being returned as JSON.

Most of product fields are static - they are changed rarely that is why we want to cache this JSON.

The problem is that we can’t cache some fields values.

For example:

1. is_favorite Boolean flag (that every product has) depends on which user is requesting products list.
2. views_count Number is updated every time product is being viewed

So how should we divide dynamic and static content for such cases?

Comment: Not sure how you want to divide the information and what you mean by divide.  BUT I think unless we know what product information there is and how you use it, then it's difficult to answer.  You can split it by the base product data and then things like 'favourite' are purely a users perspective of the product.  The view count is not really product data, but the webs perspective of the product.

Answer (score 1):

`is_favorite` and `views_count` are essentially metadata about the product that have nothing to do with the actual product.

If you have, say, a Book product, it will have `title`, `author`, `isbn`, `no_of_pages`, `genre` which are intrinsic to the book itself. No matter what context in which the book is used, those attributes will not change. The book can exist separately from these attributes. If they're both zero, it means nothing to the product. Zero may mean something to someone else, a book marketer for example but the book's existence does not depend on those two attributes. Attributes which are instrinsic to the book's existence can be cached as if they change, it's a new book.

`is_favorite` is user context while `views_count` is global context. `price`, for example is market context. All these attributes vary and perhaps shouldn't be cached (perhaps `price` can be cached for some period of time).

So that really points to longevity of attributes. The intrinsic attributes will never change so can be cached. Mid-term attributes like price may be cached but some mechanism will be needed to update them. Volatile attributes like `is_favorite` and `views_count` shouldn't be cached.

A possible implementation might be caching a local copy of a book and driving the user interface from the cached version rather than calling endpoints on each request from the user. The intrinsic attributes won't change so you only need to get them once and read from the cache after that. `is_favorite` is part of your application so you never need to read it from an endpoint after the first book `GET`. If the user makes the book a favourite, update the cached book and also `PUT` that information where it needs to be. A separate job could query the `views_count` endpoint and update the cached book intermittently. So the application relies on the cached book to do its work. Any updates from the user such as making it a favourite result in outbound `PUT` requests to the api and writes to the cached book. You don't need to `GET` an endpoint for `is_favorite` as your application is creating that information in the first place.

Comment: I understand that it should be cached but how I use it? 
Store cache and get separate endpoints for favorite_status and views_count

Comment: have added a possible way to use it